# AI software to create a rigged puppet from a photo

Tags: 3d, artificial-intelligence

I am looking for a software, free or paid, that can turn one or multiple photos of a puppet into a fully-rigged .puppet file for Adobe Character Animator or similar. The puppets look like humans and have fur, for example:

[image: sample puppet]

The resulting file would be a photorealistic 2D puppet such as "Meeb" on the [Adobe puppets page](https://pages.adobe.com/character/en/puppets).

[Headshot](https://www.reallusion.com/character-creator/headshot/) by Reallusion does this with human faces and exports in 3D formats (`.iAvatar / .fbx / .obj`).

Does the equivalent of Headshot exist for puppets and 2D output?